# Is there an IRC channel for ArcGIS or for GIS itself?

Tags: arcgis-platform

Is there an IRC channel or chat where people can talk about GIS systems, or about ArcGIS?

Comment: there is a chat on gis stackexchange, you need at least 20 reputation to use it.

Comment: It's hard to get more reputation, because I'm totally beginner in the whole GIS theme, I don't even have too much geographical study, because I'm a computer programmer. But I don't really understand the whole system of ArcGIS and the forums says only the same everywhere. The best would be to speak with somebody who relevant with the theme. And forums is a bit slow for learning and solving problems.

Comment: take a closer look at this forum. With 2 more upvotes you can chat. furthermore, you will learn faster if you first think about the questions to ask, compared with participating in a chat. Eventually, this forum is probably a faster way to have answers than the chat. Anway, I'll stop here otherwise it will become a chat room.

Comment: Try reading generally arcgis stuff in Internet and then post some specific questions about what you like at most

Answer (score 3):

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea to have [**Esri provide an IRC Channel for ArcGIS**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008D5oAAE) but so far it has garnered only a few votes.

Also, the GIS Stack Exchange provides a [**GIS Chat Room**](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142/gis) but a reputation of **20** is required to join in.

Comment: Somebody should do something, because I try to solve only one problem for a few months...with IRC it would be solved in a few hours.

Comment: Why don't you 'do' something to create one? - or get people to help, GIS SE is still a small community so the GIS SE chat seems to best answer here - getting GIS users into one location would be better than multiple chat channels.